# Nice Python wrapper for Yahoo's Geoplanet web service?

Tags: python, gis, yahoo

Has anybody created a nice wrapper around Yahoo's geo webservice "GeoPlanet" yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a brief amount of Googling, I found nothing that looks like a wrapper for this API, but I'm not quite sure if a wrapper is what is necessary for GeoPlanet.

According to Yahoo's [documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/guide/api_docs.html#api_overview) for GeoPlanet, requests are made in the form of an HTTP GET messages which can very easily be made using Python's [httplib module](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-httplib.html), and [responses](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/guide/response_formats.html) can take one of several forms including XML and JSON.  Python can very easily parse these formats.  In fact, Yahoo! itself even offers libraries for parsing both [XML](http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-xml.html)  and [JSON](http://developer.yahoo.com/python/python-json.html) with Python.

I know it sounds like a lot of libraries, but all the hard work has already been done for the programmer.  It would just take a little "gluing together" and you would have yourself a nice interface to Yahoo! GeoPlanet using the power of Python.

Comment: Thanks -- I was hoping for a more OO-like interface that hides the whole URL generation, JSON/XML parsing etc...